# SQL Error: ORA-00923: "FROM keyword not found where expected"

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

I noticed a lot of posts related to this error but in most cases there's a comma missing. I believe that's not the case here. Needless to say I'm not very experienced with Oracle.

The query triggering the error is

```
UPDATE RUBENB.METRICS 
SET (M0006,M0007) = 
(SELECT (M0004 - M0005), 
(1 - (M0004 / M0005))
FROM RUBENB.METRICS)
```

I think this **may violate DB normalization** rules but it concerns a rather small table that's supposed to render some numbers which are now calculated manually... I regret the low proficiency level of this but for now I'm seeking a quick and dirty fix to be replaced by proper reporting in the future.

Comment: The snippet you posted shouldn't throw the error you posted.  Are you sure that is the complete SQL statement?  Are you just trying to set the `M0006` column to the value of `M0004 - M0005` in the same row?  If so, there is no need to use a subquery.  Does `Metrics` have multiple rows?  If so, which `M0004 - M0005` result should be used to update a particular row of the table?

Comment: Actually, it will throw an error.  That particular error message happens a lot with oracle.  It's a catch all that means, "you did something wrong".  @beiller has the right answer.

Comment: @DanBracuk- I'm not seeing an error when I run this sqlfiddle  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/73379/1  I agree that eliminating the subquery is probably the right approach but the original query should not have thrown that error.  If there are multiple rows, it ought to have thrown a runtime error about a subquery returning multiple rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
UPDATE RUBENB.METRICS 
SET (M0006,M0007) = 
(SELECT (M0004 - M0005), 
(1 - (M0004 / M0005))
FROM RUBENB.METRICS)
```

Has to be split into two

```
UPDATE RUBENB.METRICS SET 
  M0006 = (SELECT (M0004 - M0005) FROM RUBENB.METRICS),
  M0007 = (SELECT (1 - (M0004 / M0005)) FROM RUBENB.METRICS);
```

But more likely what you want is:

```
UPDATE RUBENB.METRICS SET 
  M0006 = (M0004 - M0005),
  M0007 = (1 - (M0004 / M0005));
```